# Can VBA delete a row from a .txt file

Tags: vba, excel

I have a text file that contains:

```
Date,  Price
3/12/2015, 755
3/13/2015, 1087
```

I have some code that is inserting rows into this text file and sometimes I have to insert a correction for a date. In this example, let's say the real Price I want for 3/12/2015 is 650 instead of 755.  Is there a way to delete the 755 row and insert a row with 3/12/2015, 650 so the new file would look like:

```
Date,  Price
3/12/2015, 650
3/13/2015, 1087
```

Here is the code I am using to write to the text file:

```
FilePath = "c:\desktop\path.txt"
Set oFile = fso.OpenTextFile(FilePath, 8, True)
oFile.WriteLine Range("A13").Text & "," & Range("b13").Value
```

Thank you.

Comment: Just an idea but copy the text over to Excel and manipulate there?  Otherwise, maybe manipulate in Word as VBA plays better with MS products.

Comment: I am looking to see if it can be done keeping the txt format

Comment: Read the whole txt file into string variable, replace the necessary part with `Replace` function or with RegEx, and save resulting string back to file.